# Is it ok to regress data with different units on stata?

Tags: regression, stata

for example...

For variable trade my unit of measurement is US dollars
For GDP my unit of measurement is in peso
is it ok to regress that?

Comment: You mean predicting something in dollars with something in peso? Why not?

Comment: The only difficulty might be that the peso-to-dollar exchange rate is captured in the regression, but the complex reasons affecting changes in that exchange rate are not in the model. If you did capture the underlying reasons for changes to the exchange rate, the model would probably be so complicated as to be practically useless! If you keep in mind that data from 20 years ago reflects exchange rate reasons from 20 years ago, my answer is yes. I personally would give a smaller weight to older historical data for this reason.

Comment: ok thank you all for your help.